# How to control WordPress image metadata (using Imagick)?

Tags: php, functions, images, filters

In short, I'm having trouble with the WordPress Media Library image editor and how it handles metadata.

I use the Imagick PHP extension (but also tested with GD for comparison), and in all environments (localhost/dev/staging/prod), and with no other plugins installed/enabled, the below table shows what happened to image metadata (JPG & PNG/resized & original) post image upload. Photo's with native camera metadata and images processed with metadata set by Gimp and ExifTool were tested. Given the consistent results, I don't believe any metadata gremlins were a factor.

GD performed as I'd expected (*I understand the filters do not work for GD*).

**Imagick** however: **1.** stripped all resized .png metadata by default. & **2.** Did not change it's behavior with any of the below filters (set to either true/false - NONE of them worked).

So:
**1. Why does Imagick handle PNG's differently to JPG's?**
**2. Why didn't any of the filter/s work?** &
**3. How can I make this happen? -**
I specifically set XMP rights metadata (per [this](https://iptc.org/standards/photo-metadata/quick-guide-to-iptc-photo-metadata-and-google-images/)) on all images (.jpg/.png). When I upload them to WordPress, I would like that metadata to persist across all resized images.

Thanks in advance!

#### Results

| Processor | JPG EXIF | JPG IPTC | JPG XMP | JPG ORIG | PNG EXIF | PNG IPTC | PNG XMP | PNG ORIG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GD Only | Stripped | Stripped | Stripped | All Kept | Stripped | Stripped | Stripped | All Kept |
| GD + Any Filter | Stripped | Stripped | Stripped | All Kept | Stripped | Stripped | Stripped | All Kept |
| Imagick Only | Kept | Kept | Kept | All Kept | Stripped | Stripped | Stripped | All Kept |
| Imagick + Any Filter | Kept | Kept | Kept | All Kept | Stripped | Stripped | Stripped | All Kept |

#### Attempted Filters

```
// Fake variable to represent a true or false value. Not actually used in the functions.php file. Each filter attempted separately.
$value = 'true' || 'false'

// Filter 1
add_filter ('image_strip_meta', $value);

// Filter 2
add_filter ('image_strip_meta', '__return_$value');

// Filter 3
add_filter( 'image_strip_meta', function( $arg ) {
    return $value;
} );
```

#### Tested Hosts

***Localhost XAMPP (LAMPP)***
&
***Live Web Server***
WordPress 5.8
PHP 7.4.22

GD Extension
| GD Support | enabled |
| :------------: | :-----: |
| GD Version | bundled (2.1.0 compatible) |
| FreeType Support | enabled |
| FreeType Linkage | with freetype |
| FreeType Version | 2.4.8 |
| GIF Read Support | enabled |
| GIF Create Support | enabled |
| JPEG Support | enabled |
| libJPEG Version | 9 compatible |
| PNG Support | enabled |
| libPNG Version | 1.6.37 |
| WBMP Support | enabled |
| XBM Support | enabled |
| BMP Support | enabled |
| TGA Read Support | enabled  |

Imagick Extension
| imagick module | enabled |
| :------------: | :-----: |
| imagick module version | 3.5.1 |
| imagick classes | Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel |
| Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version | ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org |
| Imagick using ImageMagick library version | ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org |
| ImageMagick copyright | (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC |
| ImageMagick release date | 2021-01-25 |
| ImageMagick number of supported formats: | 242 |
| ImageMagick supported formats | 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, APNG, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CR3, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, FAX, FILE, FITS, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GROUP4, GV, H, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, POCKETMOD, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIDEO, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBM, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV |

Comment: I don't think filter 1 syntax is right, but 2 and 3 should work fine. It sounds like this is either a bug in the WP ImageMagick code or ImageMagick itself though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Rup - yeah I was a bit iffy on the syntax, that's why I tried a few. After all my testing it's definitely got me stumped!

Comment: @user1138 Filter 2 - did you actually use single quotes (`'`)? And filter 3 - did your actual code define the `$value` *in the function*? Have you tried without using the variable, i.e. `add_filter( 'image_strip_meta', '__return_false' )` ? (PS: Sorry about the mistakes my previous comment which I already deleted)

Comment: I did see the "Fake variable" in your post, but I just wanted to be sure. So if you actually used no variable in your actual code, then have you tried using a greater priority like 100 - `add_filter( 'image_strip_meta', '__return_false', 100 )` - did that work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SallyCJ, I actually hadn't tried setting the priority - just did it on my vanilla WP localhost and staging site (with potentially meddling plugins disabled - eg LiteSpeed Cache), and... no change. Results were still exactly as depicted in the table. :-(  And yes, that whole variable thing was totally fake, straight up values were used (e.g.  return false; or '__return_true' etc...).

Comment: So, have you resolved the issue? How, if yes? Otherwise, if you can share two images (one JPG, one PNG) containing the profiles you want to keep, I can try reproducing the issue.

Comment: No resolution as yet @SallyCJ - thanks for your offer to test! I'd be interested to hear of your results/findings. Here's a jpg and png with sample metadata for testing -  "https://ibb.co/0jFBC56" & "https://ibb.co/qRYb0g8". The jpg has bunch of EXIF/IPTC/XMP metadata. The .png contains only XMP fields I know the png format supports (and they're the ones I want anyway).

Comment: I got a helpful reply to this issue on the wordpress.org forum [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-control-wordpress-image-metadata-using-imagick/#new-topic-0). Looks like PNG metadata being stripped is how it works, so I need to test ImageMagick locally to isolate the issue. And the image_strip_meta filter doesn't work because the metadata profiles are [protected](https://github.com/wordpress/wordpress/blob/15f9f7c6b918792b8acd0b400436f615605add15/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php#L853)! It seems without removing this from the core files, the filter just wont work!

Comment: @user1138 please tag me the next time you reply to me. :) And sorry for not being able to reply earlier on. And yes, I'm aware of the protected profiles, but I thought you wanted to keep them, hence I didn't mention about the protected profiles (or I actually did, but then I deleted my comment in like a few seconds..).

Comment: Secondly, I've tested on one production site, but what I tested was the [`Imagick::getImageProfiles()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageprofiles.php) method that WordPress uses to get the image profiles, and the results are: 1) JPG - all profiles were retrieved correctly, 2) PNG - no profiles were returned (despite there was the XMP profile) - I used the sample images you provided and uploaded them via SSH. So maybe you're correct with this: "*Looks like PNG metadata being stripped is how it works*", but I'll test on another site if and when I can.

Comment: Actually, when I said, "maybe you're correct", I actually meant, maybe it is not that the metadata got stripped, but ImageMagick itself was the one that unable to read the metadata *from the PNG file* - try installing ImageMagick on your computer and run `magick meta-test.png profile.xmp` ([image](https://i.ibb.co/FB4GsY1/meta-test.png)), then see if you get any error? ( `magick This-is-a-comment.jpg profile.xmp` ([image](https://i.ibb.co/ccCb6qZ/This-is-a-comment.jpg)) should work well, though )